# ExtJS Change Button UI

Tags: extjs, theming

Using ExtJS5 I want my toolbar buttons to look like the normal ExtJS buttons.  In the documentation I see the CSS Mixins but I am not putting things together.  Can someone give me a kick in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `defaultButtonUI` in your toolbar:

```
defaultButtonUI : 'default'
```

See documentation of [defaultButtonUI](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-cfg-defaultButtonUI):

> A default ui to use for Button items. This is a quick and simple way
>   to change the look of all child Buttons.
>
> If there is no value for defaultButtonUI, the button's ui value will
>   get -toolbar appended so the Button has a different look when it's a
>   child of a Toolbar.

See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jpo

Comment: Thank you @Juan Mendes for the fiddle.